# Current Dependent Switch

Tags: mosfet, switches

I have a 24v DC circuit; I need a contact that breaks the positive line if the current in the negative line differs from the current in the positive line. So if the negative line has become broken or damaged and another earth is being found somewhere else in the system the power will be switched off.

Comment: Define power levels. Don’t you want to measure voltage rather than current? Also do you want to measure ground resistance or voltage difference on ground.? Show usage.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with something similar to a GFCI circuit.  If you run your supply and return wires through the core of a non-contact DC current sensor, you will normally read zero current since the individual flows in the wires will balance each other out.  If you have another path to ground outside the normal circuit, the supply wire will provide more current and the difference will be picked up by your sensor, which can be set for whatever level of sensitivity you want.

Comment: Current transformer won't work on DC so it'll have to be a dissimilar current sensor.

Comment: Yep, good catch, thanks; it'll have to be Hall or fluxgate.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There's pre-made DC GFI products that do this, which you should consider if you have any kind of liability issue.

For some commercial products, here's a selection:

- Littelfuse: https://www.littelfuse.com/products/protection-relays-and-controls/protection-relays/ground-fault-relays/se-601.aspx
- Automation Direct: https://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/AUTOMATION%20DIRECT/ACUAMP/DCS100-1C-24-F
- NK Technologies https://www.nktechnologies.com/ground-fault-protection/dg-series-dc-ground-fault-detector/

There's more, search for 'sensing DC ground fault'. NOTE: I'm not recommending a specific product, only illustrating examples of the the product category.

Now where does this come up legally? The NEC (National Electrical Code) was updated in 2017, which strengthens a requirement for ground fault sensing for solar and other DC systems. More about that here: https://iaeimagazine.org/safety/guide-to-ground-fault-sensing/

If all you want to do is to detect an open ground line, using a shunt sense on each line could work. That is, measure the current in each direction and check if they're equal. Another approach would be to use a DC Hall sensor across both lines: if the currents are equal, the net field will be zero; not equal, then there will be a field sensed.